# How to use multi selected dropdown in ngHandsontable 0.16

Tags: angularjs, handsontable

I am new in ngHandson table and wanted to use multi selected dropdown in my app. 
Could some one help me for multi selected dropdown using ngHandsontable?

Comment: To whoever downvoted this question, please provide some feedback as to why you downvoted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Handsontable supports multi-select dropdowns. Supported cell types are:

- Text
- Numeric
- Checkbox
- Date
- Select
- Dropdown
- Autocomplete
- Password
- Handsontable in Handsontable
- Custom

See http://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.1/tutorial-cell-types.html

What would you expect the cell value to be if multiple items were selected in the dropdown anyway?